# Neo4j Aura DB connection doesn't work when a use flask

Tags: python, flask, neo4j

I tried all day how to query a neo4j Aura DB from a Python Flask application.
When I run the following code  locally, without starting the server flask, it works:

```
import dotenv
import os
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import pandas as pd 
import time
import numpy as np


load_status = dotenv.load_dotenv("secrets/Neo4j.txt")
if load_status is False:
    raise RuntimeError('Environment variables not loaded.')

class Neo4jConnection:
    def __init__(self, uri, auth):
        self._uri = uri
        self._user = auth["user"]
        self._password = auth["password"]
        self._driver = None

    def close(self):
        if self._driver is not None:
            self._driver.close()

    def connect(self):
        self._driver = GraphDatabase.driver(self._uri, auth=(self._user, self._password))

    def run_query(self, query, parameters=None):
        with self._driver.session() as session:
            result = session.run(query, parameters)
            return result.data()

def get_user_by_proximity(distance, user_position, processed_ids):
    # Configura la tua connessione
    URI = os.getenv("NEO4J_URI")
    AUTH = {"user":os.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"),"password": os.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD")}

    # Crea una connessione
    neo4j_connection = Neo4jConnection(URI, AUTH)
    neo4j_connection.connect()
    latitude =  user_position['latitude']
    longitude = user_position['longitude']
    query = f"""
               MATCH (n:User)
               WHERE point.distance(n.location, point({{latitude: {latitude}, longitude:{longitude}}}))/1000 <= {distance}
               AND NOT n.`_id` IN {processed_ids}
               RETURN n"""
    result =  neo4j_connection.run_query(query)
    neo4j_connection.close()
    return result

def get_score():
   <other stuff>
```

But when I launch the flask server, calling that piece of code, it gives me this error:

```
from flask import Flask
from match import *

app = Flask(__name__)


user = {<MANY INFO>}

@app.route('/')
def index(userInfo=None):
  group = get_score(user)
  return group

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

>>>ServiceUnavailable
    neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Unable to retrieve routing information
```

The connection URI begins with the "neo4j+s://..." protocol and I am using a free instance of Aura DB, maybe that is the problem. Is there a way to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Related thread: https://community.neo4j.com/t/unable-to-retrieve-routing-information/44203